# Why are my time conversions inconsistent?

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono

Quick background: my application accesses multiple data sources that report timestamped data, each timestamp is reported as Unix epoch seconds, e.g. data reports `1656331210`. The user can input a requested time to report as an ISO date string, such as `2022-06-27T12:00:10Z`. These two values are considered equivalent. My problem is consistently converting back and forth.

My function `formatTimestamp` shown below correctly converts the given timestamp value to an ISO string. However, my function to convert from a string to the same value produces a different value. I know there is an error in my logic and/or understanding.

(As a side note, I've scoured the docs for `chrono` and Howard Hinnant's date.h libraries for understanding as well. I stumble greatly on converting from one type to another and can never seem to come up with a simple and consistent solution. I know there is one, but I'm not there yet.)

Please take a look at my sample code below and correct the error of my ways:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

uint64_t from_isoTimeString(std::string iso_time_string)
{
   //--- takes an UTC ISO formatted time/date string and converts it to a timestamp value
   std::tm tmb;
   std::stringstream ss(iso_time_string);
   ss >> std::get_time(&tmb, "%Y-%m-%dT%TZ");
   if (ss.fail())
   {
      std::string errmsg = "unable to convert Timestamp '" + iso_time_string + "' from ISO 8601 format";
      throw std::invalid_argument(errmsg);
   }

   std::time_t tt;
   tt = mktime(&tmb);              // returns 1656345610, expecting 1656331210
   tt = mktime(&tmb) - _timezone;  // returns 1656327610, expecting 1656331210
   return static_cast<uint64_t>(tt);
}

std::string formatTimestamp(uint64_t epoch_seconds, std::string timestamp_format)
{
   std::time_t tt = epoch_seconds;

   std::tm tmb;
   gmtime_s(&tmb, &tt);

   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << std::put_time(&tmb, timestamp_format.c_str());
   if (ss.fail())
   {
      std::string err_msg = "unable to convert Timestamp to " + timestamp_format + " format";
      throw std::invalid_argument(err_msg);
   }
   return ss.str();
}


int main() 
{
   uint64_t time1_uint = 1656331210;
   std::string time1_str = "2022-06-27T12:00:10Z";

   std::cout << "            time1_str: " << time1_str << std::endl;
   std::cout << " time1_uint as string: " << formatTimestamp(time1_uint, "%Y-%m-%dT%TZ" ) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "           time1_uint: " << time1_uint << std::endl;
   std::cout << "time1_str from string: " << from_isoTimeString(time1_str) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the C time API can be very confusing for your use case because it involves conversions to and from your local time zone, which is a completely unnecessary complication.

Fwiw, I've rewritten your conversion functions in terms of my date.h header below:

```
uint64_t
from_isoTimeString(std::string iso_time_string)
{
   //--- takes an UTC ISO formatted time/date string and converts it to a timestamp value
   date::sys_seconds tmb;
   std::stringstream ss(iso_time_string);
   ss >> date::parse("%Y-%m-%dT%TZ", tmb);
   if (ss.fail())
   {
      std::string errmsg = "unable to convert Timestamp '" + iso_time_string + "' from ISO 8601 format";
      throw std::invalid_argument(errmsg);
   }
   return static_cast<uint64_t>(tmb.time_since_epoch().count());
}

std::string
formatTimestamp(uint64_t epoch_seconds, std::string timestamp_format)
{
   date::sys_seconds tt{std::chrono::seconds{epoch_seconds}};

   std::stringstream ss;
   ss << date::format(timestamp_format, tt);
   if (ss.fail())
   {
      std::string err_msg = "unable to convert Timestamp to " + timestamp_format + " format";
      throw std::invalid_argument(err_msg);
   }
   return ss.str();
}
```

I've changed as little as possible within each function.  Now your local time zone is not part of the computation.  And this code will easily port to C++20 (when available) by changing a few `date::` to `std::chrono::` or `std::`.

Your `main()` needs no changes at all, and the output is now:

```
            time1_str: 2022-06-27T12:00:10Z
 time1_uint as string: 2022-06-27T12:00:10Z
           time1_uint: 1656331210
time1_str from string: 1656331210
```

Comment: Thanks @HowardHinnant... I knew it was something fairly straightforward. The simplicity of your library is apparent as I read the docs. It's applying it to my own situation that in which I stumble a bit. I appreciate your help.